# Why is sumif not adding the row values?

Tags: google-sheets

I apologize in advance if I am missing something basic.

Trying to use a sumif that checks if col b2 has an A.  If it does, I want to add the scores in columns c2-g2 and put the value in h2.  PROBLEM is it is only putting the value for column c2 instead of adding c2-g2

What am I missing? The formula in H2  `=sumif(B2,"A",C2:G2)`

[picture of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb3Ua.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BTM0-7yxJZcuyl_owpWwgXFj6tH5h1FMOUfoZ6LA7Hs/edit?usp=sharing
it is the class scores sheet

Comment: That's not how SO works. We don't go somewhere else to get information needed for your question. All relevant information needs to be here, in the question itself, in the form of a [mre]. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: the question does have a minimal reproducible example.  thanks for your concern

Comment: Not here in the question itself. You've linked to it and provided an image that can't be copied and pasted from to reproduce the issue. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/62576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike,
sumif is a great tool but I prefer to keep things in an Array where possible.  Here is a good way to approach the same problem.

```
=Array_Constrain(ArrayFormula(If(B2:B = "A",C2:C+D2:D+E2:E+F2:F+G2:G,0)),CountIF(A2:A,"<>"),1)
```

Place that formula in H2 and delete the rest of the formulas below.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is easy to use [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) and [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en) combined instead of [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)

```
=IF(B2="A", SUM(C2:G2), 0)
```

Comment: I just want to chime in here for accuracy. SUMIF does work with arrays; you just have to know how to structure it to do so. This isn't to criticize you, only to present fuller information for this poster and for future site visitors.